# How to allow selectInput list to overflow bounds of absolutePanel in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app that lets the user select from a set of inputs, which updates the points shown on a map. The controls are placed in an `absolutePanel` and I would like the height of panel to increase/decrease as determined by the number of items in each respective `selectInput` list. Is there a way to access the height of the `selectInputList` or otherwise set the height of the `absolutePanel` to be flexible? Thanks in advance!

Example below:

app.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

foo <- c("first", "first", "first", "first", "second", "second", "second", "second", "third", "third")
bar <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c")
lat <- c(41.1,41.2,41.3,41.4,41.5,41.6,41.7,41.8,41.9,41.10)
lon <- c(-4.1,-4.2,-4.3,-4.4,-4.5,-4.6,-4.7,-4.8,-4.9,-4.10)

df_tmp <- data.frame(foo, bar, lat, lon, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

icon <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'home',
  iconColor = '#00CCFF',
  library = 'fa',
  markerColor = 'gray'
)

firstList <- setNames(foo, foo)
secondList <- setNames(bar, bar)

# ---------------------- UI ----------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Foo",
    titleWidth = 220
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 220,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "First Tab",
        tabName = "firstTab",
        icon = icon("map-signs")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "firstTab",
        div(
          class = "outer",
          tags$head(
            includeCSS("www/styles.css")
          ),
          leafletOutput("firstMapOutput", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
          absolutePanel(
            id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
            draggable = TRUE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
            width = 330, height = "auto",

            h3("Controls"),

            selectInput(
              inputId = "firstMapFirstSelection",
              label = "First",
              choices = firstList,
              selected = "first",
              multiple = TRUE
            ),
            selectInput(
              inputId = "firstMapSecondSelection",
              label = "Second",
              choices = secondList,
              selected = "a",
              multiple = TRUE
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
  ##### ---------------------- SERVER -----
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$firstMapOutput <- renderLeaflet({
      selectedData <- reactive({
        df_tmp %>%
          filter(
            foo == input$firstMapFirstSelection &
            bar == input$firstMapSecondSelection
          ) 
      })
      leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
        addAwesomeMarkers(
          lng = ~lon,
          lat = ~lat,
          icon = icon,
          data = selectedData()
        )
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

styles.css:

```
input[type="number"] {
  max-width: 80%;
}

div.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 41px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  padding: 0;
}

/* Customize fonts */
body, label, input, button, select { 
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
  font-weight: 200;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 { font-weight: 400; }

#controls {
  /* Appearance */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  cursor: move;
  /* Fade out while not hovering */
  opacity: 0.65;
  zoom: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 500ms 1s;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#controls:hover {
  /* Fade in while hovering */
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

/* Position and style citation */
#cite {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* If not using map tiles, show a white background */
.leaflet-container {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to overwrite the default positioning behaviour of the select input list. Instead of absolute positioning, which means it does not reflow the sibling and parent elements, you want them to be static. Static elements *take up space* and will embiggen the size of the surrounding conditional panel. (Conditional panel size is flexible by default.)

The css rule would be

```
.selectize-control .selectize-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}
```

[image: static dropdown]

Comment: Thanks, you made my day!